# Can I substitute a top round beef roast with a beef rib eye roast?

Tags: beef

I have a recipe that calls for a 7 lb. top round beef roast with full fat cap. You salt the beef for 2 days and then set oven for 450 and roast for 20 min. Reduce to 225 and roast for 1 hr. 30 min. Can I use a beef rib eye boneless roast instead of the top round beef roast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You may want to baste from time to time if there's little fat, and ribeye benefits from lower and slower cooking--which you pretty much seem to have here--but otherwise yes. You may wish to check out *Ad Hoc at Home*, by Thomas Keller, which discusses roasting a ribeye.